# PHP select box with multiple options in of times and dates

Tags: php, html

I want to have a select box on my website that has multiple options in (up to 3 days in the future from today)

and to display options like:

```
<optgroup>Wednesday 8th Janurary (tomorrow)</optgroup>
<option>08:00 - 10:00</option>
<option>10:00 - 12:00</option>
```

from `09:00` to `17:00` each day and going up to 3 days in the future

i found this on the internet but im not too sure how to finish it how i want this:

```
$start = "11:00";
    $end = "13:30";

    $tStart = strtotime($start);
    $tEnd = strtotime($end);
    $tNow = $tStart;

    while($tNow <= $tEnd){
      echo date("H:i",$tNow)."\n";
      $tNow = strtotime('+30 minutes',$tNow);
    }
```

UPDATE:

I also tried this:

```
<select name="time">
    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) {
        echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.date("h.iA", strtotime("$i:00")).'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

but its just showing all times

**UPDATE:**

Ok update from answer:

I have tried doing:

```
<select name="time"><?php
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; ++$i) {
        echo '<optgroup label="'.date('l j F', strtotime('+ ' . $i . ' day')).'">';
        for ($n = 9; $n < 16; $n = $n + 3) {
            if(!$n > date("H")) {
                echo '<option>'.$n.':00 - '.($n+2).':00</option>';
            }
        }
        echo '</optgroup>';
    }
    ?></select>
```

where i added in the if statement its now not showing any times. i want to remove the times that have already occurred if possible?

Comment: That's nice. What's your question?

Comment: did you try anything? show us your effort first?

Comment: check my update of code

Comment: The OP did show efforts, he found something on the internet. That's more than we can say for some posts on here.

Comment: you need to display the times automatically from 9 to 17 right?

Comment: not all the time, min time is 09:00 and max time is 17:00 so i want to make it display the times that havnt occurred yet. for example, lets say the current time is 15:00 it will then show 15:00-17:00 and no other times for today and then all times from 09:00-17:00 for another two days in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want it to start at 09:00, finish at 17:00, and have two hour slots per option?

Then this:

```
<select>

<?php for ($i = date('G') < 17 ? 0 : 1; $i <= 2; ++$i) { ?>

  <optgroup label="<?php echo date('l j F', strtotime('+ ' . $i . ' day')); echo !$i ? ' (Today)' : (1 === $i ? ' (Tomorrow)' : ''); ?>">

    <?php for ($n = 9; $n < 16; $n += 2) { if ($i || date('G', strtotime('+ 15 minutes')) < $n + 2) { ?>

      <option><?php echo str_pad($n, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>:00 - <?php echo str_pad($n + 2, 2, '0'); ?>:00</option>

    <?php } } ?>

  </optgroup>

<?php } ?>

</select>
```

Comment: yep nearly! how can i make the times disappear if they have occurred? for example, its showing todays times and has all 3 options which are no longer available?

Comment: This shows the time from 9 today which OP didn't want and 4 days instead of 3

Comment: @putvande, the 9:00am exclusion wasn't in the question and he said up to 3 days in the future, which I understood as today + 3 days.

Comment: how can i make it put today and tomorrow in brackets next to the days that are today and tomorrow?

Comment: excellent thanks. sorry one more :) - lets say its 13:45 (15 minutes before the end time of 14:00 could you make the 12:00 - 14:00 not display

Comment: Sorry - i have just noticed that it has 12:00-14:00 and then 15:00-17:00, is it possible to make it 12:00-14:00 and then 14:00-16:00 and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I have only made some minor modifications on Mr.MichaelRushton effort. To me the credit goes to Mr. MichaelRushton. But still here it is

```
    <select>

<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; ++$i) { ?>

  <optgroup label="<?php echo date('l j F', strtotime('+ ' . $i . ' day')); ?>">
    <?php if($i==0) { ?>
    <?php for ($n = date('H'); $n < 16; $n += 3) { ?>
      <option><?php echo str_pad($n, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>:00 - <?php echo str_pad($n + 2, 2, '0'); ?>:00</option>
    <?php } }?> 
    <?php for ($n = 9; $n < 16; $n = $n + 3) { ?>

      <option><?php echo str_pad($n, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>:00 - <?php echo str_pad($n + 2, 2, '0'); ?>:00</option>

    <?php } ?>

  </optgroup>

<?php } ?>

</select>
```